# Analysis frame centering for scipy.signal.stft (and matplotlib plotting discrepancy)

Tags: matplotlib, audio, scipy, signal-processing

I'm doing some experiments with Scipy's STFT, and would like to confirm that I'm understanding things correctly.

The following code generates the image I would expect, but labeled with the wrong time values:

```
from math import ceil, log
from scipy.io.wavfile import read
from scipy.signal import stft
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# read a 2s, 440 Hz test tone, padded with 0.5s of silence on either end
fs, x = read('a440_2s_padded.wav')
nperseg = 44100
# pick an FFT size that's the smallest power of 2 >= the window size
nfft = pow(2, ceil(log(nperseg, 2)))
# N.B. no overlap between windows
f, t, Zxx = stft(x, fs, 'blackman', nperseg=nperseg, noverlap=0, nfft=nfft, boundary='zeros')

# crop the display to relevant bins
minBin, maxBin = 600, 700

# plot it
plt.pcolormesh(t, f[minBin:maxBin], np.abs(Zxx[minBin:maxBin]), vmin=None, vmax=None)
plt.title('STFT Magnitude')
plt.ylabel('Frequency [Hz]')
plt.xlabel('Time [sec]')
plt.show()
```

[matplotlib STFT output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oW15F.png)

As noted in the code, I'm analyzing a 2s, 440 Hz test tone, padded with 0.5s of silence on either end, but in the image, the signal starts at 1s and lasts until 3s.  For small `nperseg` values, this discrepancy doesn't make much difference, but for large values and musical data, the difference can be substantial, as it determines whether the STFT is centering its frames *within* beats (the desired behavior), or *on* beats (undesired, because then it's smearing data from two consecutive beats).

Am I misunderstanding something about the STFT analysis settings?  Thanks for any insight.